# Custom array from a query only write the last row of the query

Tags: php, plugin-development, mysql, wpdb

Looking for some input on this one. I am writing a custom array but having a strange issue. It seems to be cycling through the loop and dropping previous values and only storing the last row of the query. Any ideas?

```
global $wpdb;
$queryresult = $wpdb->get_results(select query);

$modified_result = array();

foreach($queryresult as $result){
    $modified_result['name'] = $result->name;
    $modified_result['address'] = $result->address;
}

$datadump = json_encode($modified_result);
echo file_put_contents('my_output.json', $datadump);

// outputs {"name":"Mark","address":"1313 Mockingbird Lane"}
// which is only the LAST row in the query instead of
// building an array of ALL names and addresses that should be
// produced by the loop. Any ideas anyone?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you're not adding elements to the array. You're overwriting them:

```
$modified_result = array();

foreach($queryresult as $result){
    $modified_result['name'] = $result->name;
    $modified_result['address'] = $result->address;
}
```

Your loop is setting the `name` and `address` property of the `$modified_result` array directly, and then replacing them for each item in the loop.

You want `$modified_result` to be an array *of arrays*, which means that for each `$result` you need to add a new array to `$modified_result`. You can do this with `$modified_result[]`:

```
$modified_result = array();

foreach ( $queryresult as $result ) {
    $modified_result[] = array(
        'name'    => $result->name,
        'address' => $result->address,
    );
}
```

That being said, I can't see any reason from you code why you can't just query the fields you want to begin with. Then you don't need the loop at all:

```
$queryresult = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT name, address FROM ..." );

$datadump = json_encode( $queryresult );
echo file_put_contents( 'my_output.json', $datadump );
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks for your help. The reason why I didn't query the fields directly is because I am running a custom function against one of the columns that modifies the value and sends it to a custom array for another use in my plugin across several lookup functions.
-Cheers!